# How to create a matrix colored plot from a list of lists (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

My question is:  imagine you have a list of length 484 and each element of the list is also a list of length of 484. Basically these lists in the list are going to be the rows in my matrix. I was wandering how can I plot this matrix and the color it based on the values of the matrix.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`plt.matshow(my_list)`

This would work for your nested list but in general you can convert your nested list into a matrix by calling:

`my_array = np.asarray(my_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
plt.imshow(your_array, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: @DPM Yes, you should try.